# codeigniter how to enable segment base urls and query string url at the same time

Tags: codeigniter

Please note I am using codeigniter 3.0.3.

In my current project I want to use both query string and segment base url. When I enable

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE
```

segment base stopped working. I have used all options of uri protocol e.g.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'; //REQUEST_URI,QUERY_STRING
```

Is there any way to use both with out any errors. I want to use url helpers in segmented url's and at few places I want to use query strings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking URI.php core class, it can be seen that query appendix is meant to work when config uri protocol is set to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

You don't need to set

```
config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

option to `true` if you want to be able to grab key=value from URI. It is needed only if you want query strings without segments in URI.

> You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
>
> example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here

So your options should be

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```