# CodeIgniter query string url and segment base url?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to use a segment base URL and a query string URL with CodeIgniter at the same time, and in the same project, for example `http://localhost/finance_new/login/logout` and `http://[::1]/finance_new/?c=login&m=logout`.

When I set `enable_query_string` to `true`, it only works for the second pattern but not for the first.

How can I use both URLs?

I am using CodeIgniter version 3.0.

Comment: does it is working with http://localhost/finance_new/login/logout?

Comment: Try change `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947577/codeigniter-how-to-enable-segment-base-urls-and-query-string-url-at-the-same-tim "codeigniter how to enable segment base urls and query string url at the same time"

Answer (score 0):

You probably forget to set `base_url()` in `application/config/config.php`.

Just set `base_url()` like this..

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/finance_new/';
```

Then

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: I set base_url but it is not working..always it redirect to  default controller

Comment: could you post your routes.php?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` at the place of `[::1]`.

Comment: Not working  not working...i use my ip address http://192.168.0.40/finance_new/configuration/edit_bank/241..also use 127.0.0.1 but not working

Comment: Not working..I use my local ip address...also use 127.0.0.1..same as before- http://192.168.0.40/finance_new/configuration/edit_bank/241